# While running "npm run prod" getting this "CssSyntaxError: /css/style.css:118:18: Missed semicolon" in Laravel reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, laravel

I am using Laravel and reactjs and when I am using `npm run dev` everything works fine but when I run `npm run prod` command I get errors in my console as follows:

> CssSyntaxError: /css/style.css:118:18: Missed semicolon
>       at Input.error (/home/iron/Documents/reactify/reactify-dev/reactify-laravel/reactify-redux-thunk/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:130:16)
>       at Parser.checkMissedSemicolon (/home/react/Documents/react/react-dev/react-laravel/react-thunk/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:603:22)
>       at Parser.decl (/home/iron/Documents/react/react-dev/react-laravel/reactify-thunk/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:286:46)

If you need any files let me know.

Comment: `If you need any files let me know.` Well, to be honest, in order to resolve your issue, you need to show a snippet of code where you think the error might be.

Answer (score 2):

Error already is self explanatory, `CssSyntaxError: /css/style.css:118:18: Missed semicolon`

it tells you to look in `/css/style.css` file for missing semicolon on line 118

Comment: In addition to the author of the answer, I think there should be a linter on every application we're developing to avoid this kind of compiling issues.